# google cloud storage maximum objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Folks,

I'm uploading the contents of a data drive to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.  After ~90% of the data successfully transferred, the bucket wouldn't accept any more date.  I couldn't even create an empty folder.

I've found a reference to object name lengths and file size but nothing about count maximums.

It fails silently, without error message, acting like the command is being ignored.

I'm using Google's console (no code of my own).

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Cloud Storage has no limit. What are you using to upload?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage objects can be multiple terabytes in size. You can upload billions of objects into a single bucket. Object names can be as large as one kibibyte.

It's possible you have encountered some sort of bug. Do you see any JavaScript errors in the console or anything like that? Have you tried uploading the object in a manner other than using the console, perhaps with the `gsutil` command line utility?